# Lower and upper bounds on conditional expected value.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ which can take negative values. I am wondering if it is possible to find exact or high-probable lower and bounds for $\mathbb{E}(X|X\ge a)$ based on $a$, $var(X)$ or $\mathbb{E}(x)$ assuming that $a$ is positive and $p$-quantile.